# How to Return Translated text in node.js google-translate-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, node-modules

Hi Every One I want to pass a variable to google-translate-api translate function . how can i do that.

```
translate(txt, {from: 'en', to: 'ja'}).then(res => {
  var translated=res.text;
  return translated;
});
consol.log(translated);
```

But the result I got **undefinded**  Please tell me how  to return translated text

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log the "translated" variable in wrong scope. You should move console.log function into the callback method (I mean into "then" function).

```
translate(txt, {from: 'en', to: 'ja'}).then(res => {
  consol.log(res.text);
});
```

But if you want to use the translated value out of function, you can use "await" (more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
async function myTranslateFn(text){
   var res = await translate(text, {from: 'en', to: 'ja'}); 
   return res.text;
}

var result = myTranslateFn("flower");
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I Got translated text value out of .then function

Comment: @Afzal translate function is async, so you can use "await" keyword for it. I added another code piece to my answer

Comment: Hi #Sercan ozen  One more question .

Comment: Yes sure, you can ask

Comment: How can I pass a variable to .then function means how to get original text that is going to be translated in .then function . in for loop translate function get random index value of array and then translate . I want to get both translated text and to be translated text in .then function . Above function works for one time execution but not in for loop. In For loop txt that we pass to be translated Only get last index value of array

Comment: You can create a promise that wraps translate method and you can send two of parameters using resolve method.  https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve
PS: translate method is also a promise

Comment: @Sercanözen, I want to call translate() in loop. I tried with async await as you shown.. But getting **Bad Request** error..

Comment: @JaynaTanawala, you're passing the translate api usage limit in your loop -> https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas?hl=en.  Perhaps you can put some sleep between translations.

Comment: @Sercanözen, I call api in setTimeout() for 5 sec.. Initially I am getting logs of converted text but after few call from translate(), it started throwing **Too many requests with code: Bad Request**.

Comment: @JaynaTanawala I guess it's same error so it's about the api's limits. You need to increase timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the translate call with a function and pass a callback to the outer function

```
callTranslate(txt, fn) {
    translate(txt, {from: 'en', to: 'ja'}).then(res => {
      fn(res.text);
    });
}
```

Now whenever you have to call the translate API, do it like:

```
callTranslate('yourText', (translated) => { console.log(translated); })
// add any logic in the callback itself if you want to further process the result
```